# Number of matches in regex substitution

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a Pythonic way to simplify this code:

```
fix = re.compile(r'((?<=>\n)(\t){2}(?=<))')
fixed_output = re.sub(fix, 1*2*' ', fixed_output)
fix = re.compile(r'((?<=>\n)(\t){3}(?=<))')
fixed_output = re.sub(fix, 2*2*' ', fixed_output)
# and so on...
```

That is: if there are *n* tab characters between ">" and "<", they are replaced by *(n-1) * 2* characters. Can this be generalized to a single regular expression? In other words, is it possible to write a regular expression that uses the number of matches in order to determine the replacement string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function instead of a fixed replacement string and take the number of matched tabulator characters to generate the replacement, for example:

```
re.sub(r'((?<=>\n)\t{2,}(?=<))', lambda m: (len(m.group(0))-1)*2*" ", string)
```

Here the [lambda expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda) `lambda m: (len(m.group(0))-1)*2*" "` is used to replace *n* tabulator character by (*n*-1)·2 spaces.